# JQuery Rounded Corners with Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, rounded-corners

I'd like to create a dropdown menu with rounded corners without using images. I tried combining the suckerfish menu plugin with a number of the JQuery rounded corners plugins, which mostly worked fine in Firefox, but looked terrible in IE.

Does anybody have an easy combination of plug-ins that will work with both IE and Firefox?

Comment: Why not use regular border-radius (CSS3)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try [DD Roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/)?  I've had pretty good cross-browser success with this code, it also fixes background image transparent pngs, the only code library I've found that actually did this on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS3 [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius) and if really necessary, [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for IE<9 compatibility.